# Join site when trying to upvote

Tags: bug

I can ask question on the wrong site. (bug report is misleading, my mistake)

I can add comments, but cannot delete or edit comments.

[image]

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: SAMSUNG-SM-G920A

  - OS Version: 6.0.1 (G920AUCS6DQC1)

Comment: this can be closed,  session required manual revalidation

Comment: FYI, this is happening to me as well on the iOS app.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually signed in with your user account as that is the requirement to vote?

https://serverfault.com/help/why-register

> Registration is not required to participate on Stack Exchange; you can read, answer, and suggest edits as an anonymous user, much like on Wikipedia. There are **some things you won’t be able to do** on the site without registering, however, **such as vote.**

Comment: posted here without an issue....so

Comment: manually logged out and in and now it's fine.

Comment: @JacobEvans In the text quoted in the response, posting is not listed as one of the things you cna't do without registering/logging in. So the fact that you could post here is entirely orthagonal to the issue.

Comment: don't comments require rep points?

Comment: You can alway comment on your own questions and answers, anonymous users as well, for as long as the cookie associating them with their posts remains valid, IIRC